# Django - Save only time and validate start time is earlier than end time

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a Django Model -

```py
class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contactNumber = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact number')
    startTime = models.TimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now,add = False)
    endTime = models.TimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now,add = False)
```

How do I ensure that startTime is always less than endTime ?

Comment: Why not use a `TimeField`? This will reduce a lot of validation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but that also puts in a date, right?

Comment: no that is a `DateTimeField`, a `TimeField` only stores *time*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#timefield

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what about pre validation before saving?

Comment: I think it is better to create a form for this model and verify there?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar I came across the`save` method override. But i am not sure about how to use it

Comment: @PrateekNarendra: please *don't* implement this in the `save()` method. It will result in the form being considered valid, if it is not.

Comment: In addition to that, the user will not see the `errors` in the form but a 500 http response

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem its alright. We'll be integrating it with React to handle it.

Comment: @PrateekNarendra: but regardless, a 500 error is one of the most "uninformative" errors there is. Furthermore if the database does not make use of transactions, it means you can move the database to an inconsistent state. So it is not only *inconvenient* but also *unsafe*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`TimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#timefield). This will fetch objects and present these as [**`datetime.time`** objects [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time). Furthermore it attaches some default widgets to it, that make it more convenient to work with forms where you enter time.

You thus can define this in your model with:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contactNumber = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact number')
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
```

You can then override [**`Model.clean()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) to check if `start` is less than or equal to `end`. Furthermore since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2) you can make use of the [*Django constraint framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint), and try to enforce the constraints at the *database side* as well. Not all databases support this however:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import Q, F

class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contactNumber = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact number')
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.start > self.end:
            raise ValidationError('Start should be before end')
        return super().clean()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(start__lte=F('end')),
                name='start_before_end')
            )
        ]
```

Comment: what is `Q` and `F` ? I cannot find documentation for those imports.

Comment: @PrateekNarendra: a [**`Q`**-object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) is basically the representation of a "query" (a condition), whereas [**`F`** expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) refer to a "field" (or a lookup on that field).